# Generate Code Coverage with Appium on iOS

Tags: ios, testing, appium, code-coverage

is it possible to generate code coverage on ios?
I am using wdio to execute my UI tests.

I followed the instructions can be found here, but it does not seem working:

[Code Coverage with Appium for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233514/code-coverage-with-appium-for-ios)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I personally user [Generamba](https://github.com/strongself/Generamba). It's a gem where you can install some templates and then generate both your .swift files to work and the tests. 
It's really usefull for cases where you work with VIPER architecture where you have a lot of swift files that only change in the Module name variable.